# Performing svd by sklearn.decomposition.PCA , how can I get the U S V from this?

Tags: python, pca, svd

I perform SVD with [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

From the equation of the SVD

> A= U x S x V_t

V_t = transpose matrix of V
(Sorry I can't paste the original equation)

If I want the matrix U, S, and V, how can I get it if I use the [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, depending on the size of your matrix, sklearn implementation of `PCA` will not always compute the full SVD decomposition. The following is taken from [PCA's GitHub reciprocity](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py):

```
svd_solver : string {'auto', 'full', 'arpack', 'randomized'}
        auto :
            the solver is selected by a default policy based on `X.shape` and
            `n_components`: if the input data is larger than 500x500 and the
            number of components to extract is lower than 80% of the smallest
            dimension of the data, then the more efficient 'randomized'
            method is enabled. Otherwise the exact full SVD is computed and
            optionally truncated afterwards.
        full :
            run exact full SVD calling the standard LAPACK solver via
            `scipy.linalg.svd` and select the components by postprocessing
        arpack :
            run SVD truncated to n_components calling ARPACK solver via
            `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`. It requires strictly
            0 < n_components < X.shape[1]
        randomized :
            run randomized SVD by the method of Halko et al.
```

In addition, it also performs some manipulations on the data (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681972/different-results-for-pca-truncated-svd-and-svds-on-numpy-and-sklearn)).

Now, if you want to get `U, S, V` that are used in `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` you can use `pca._fit(X)`. 
For example:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3,5], [8,10], [-1, 1], [5,6]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca._fit(X)
```

prints

```
(array([[ -3.55731195e-01,   5.05615563e-01],
        [  2.88830295e-04,  -3.68261259e-01],
        [  7.10884729e-01,  -2.74708608e-01],
        [ -5.68187889e-01,  -4.43103380e-01],
        [  2.12745524e-01,   5.80457684e-01]]),
 array([ 9.950385  ,  0.76800941]),
 array([[ 0.69988535,  0.71425521],
        [ 0.71425521, -0.69988535]]))
```

However, if you just want the SVD decomposition of the original data, I would suggest to use [scipy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, so it's hard for me. One more question is if the data size is very large, what is better between 'randomized' and 'full'. What should I choose for my dataset? Is the result between 'randomized' and 'full' different?

Comment: One option is just not to choose, and then the default would be 'auto', and the solver will chose which method to use (based on the matrix size and number of components). The idea is that if the matrix very large and if you don't need all the components (that is, you need 80% of the smallest dimension of the data) then doing randomized svd is more efficient and you don't loose much by doing that. In any case if you do need all the components (or more than 80%), then 'auto' guarantee that full svd will be used. The randomized svd is based on this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf